# Exigir login do usuário para visualização de categorias

Tags: php, opencart

Tenho uma loja desenvolvida com OpenCart e gostaria que fosse necessário login do cliente para acessar uma determinada categoria de produtos.

Existe algum módulo que faça isso? Ou é possível fazer diretamente no código.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack overflow. Da maneira que está sua pergunta ela fornece poucos detalhes e não demonstra esforços de pesquisa. Comece fazendo um [tour] e leia o guia [ask]

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque não demonstrou um esforço minimo do autor para resolução do problema.